# unable to get the correct xpath in soapUI

Tags: xpath, soapui

I am unable to fetch the correct xpath for the below schema. Any help would be great

```
> <soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
> <soapenv:Header>
>       <ns1:ABC soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
> soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://ABCT.XYZ.com">
>          <ns2:type xmlns:ns2="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">response</ns2:type>
>          <ns3:service xmlns:ns3="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
>             <ns3:name>ABCT2 Client</ns3:name>
>             <ns3:version>1.0.0</ns3:version>
>          </ns3:service>
>          <ns4:originator xmlns:ns4="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">ABCT20</ns4:originator>
>          <ns5:businessProcessName xmlns:ns5="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">whaaiaia</ns5:businessProcessName>
>          <ns6:requestDateTime xmlns:ns6="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">2022-06-23T14:02:59.995Z</ns6:requestDateTime>
>          <ns7:sourceSystemTransactionId xmlns:ns7="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">77888877</ns7:sourceSystemTransactionId>
>          <ns8:user xmlns:ns8="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
>             <ns8:id>bbb</ns8:id>
>             <ns8:group>ccc</ns8:group>
>          </ns8:user>
>          <ns9:transactionReference xmlns:ns9="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">b65787</ns9:transactionReference>
>          <ns10:result xmlns:ns10="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
>             <ns10:status>success</ns10:status>
>             <ns10:provider>PQR</ns10:provider>
>          </ns10:result>
>       </ns1:ABC>    </soapenv:Header>

I need to get the success response tag.
```

Comment: Your sample XML data is not well formed. You will need to fix the XML before you can apply XPath to it

Comment: could you please let me know what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your current edit is better, but it's still not well-formed. I've taken your current data and removed all the `>` from the start of each line and added the missing `</soapenv:Envelope>` closing tag to produce this well-formed XML document:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:ABC soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://ABCT.XYZ.com">
            <ns2:type xmlns:ns2="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">response</ns2:type>
            <ns3:service xmlns:ns3="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
                <ns3:name>ABCT2 Client</ns3:name>
                <ns3:version>1.0.0</ns3:version>
            </ns3:service>
            <ns4:originator xmlns:ns4="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">ABCT20</ns4:originator>
            <ns5:businessProcessName xmlns:ns5="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">whaaiaia</ns5:businessProcessName>
            <ns6:requestDateTime xmlns:ns6="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">2022-06-23T14:02:59.995Z</ns6:requestDateTime>
            <ns7:sourceSystemTransactionId xmlns:ns7="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">77888877</ns7:sourceSystemTransactionId>
            <ns8:user xmlns:ns8="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
                <ns8:id>bbb</ns8:id>
                <ns8:group>ccc</ns8:group>
            </ns8:user>
            <ns9:transactionReference xmlns:ns9="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">b65787</ns9:transactionReference>
            <ns10:result xmlns:ns10="http://ABC.XYZ.com/header">
                <ns10:status>success</ns10:status>
                <ns10:provider>PQR</ns10:provider>
            </ns10:result>
        </ns1:ABC>
    </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There are a number of ways you could query for the "success" response flag contained in the `status` element: e.g. here's one:

```
//*[local-name()='status' and namespace-uri()='http://ABC.XYZ.com/header']
```

That expression evaluates to the `status` element containing the text "success". If you just want to check if the status is successful, you could use this XPath expression instead:

```
//*[local-name()='status' and namespace-uri()='http://ABC.XYZ.com/header']='success'
```

That will return the boolean value `true`.

Note you could query for the status element with an XPath like this:

```
//ns1:status
```

... or

```
//ns1:status='success'
```

... but first you will need to bind the `ns1` prefix to the namespace URI `http://ABC.XYZ.com/header`, and how you would do that depends on what software you are using to evaluate the XPath. Using the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` functions is a way to query for the element with a particular namespaced name, but without having to do that binding.

Comment: SoapUI supports wildcards for namespaces. So `//*:status` is perfectly fine.